# Spacing rules: Is it 가 보다 or 가보다?

Tags: spacing

In the combination "verb + 보다" (= try doing), is there supposed to be a space between the two words or not?

Example: 우리 한 번 가 보자! Let's go one time! (lit. Let's try going one time!)

Comment: Both are correct. http://korean.stackexchange.com/a/118/109

Comment: That answers this question. Should we close this question? Add a link to that question?

Comment: @파울울 There is no serious problem, so it need not be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *technically* correct to include the space. However, it is *extremely* common (technically incorrect but *officially allowed*) to omit the space. In other words, both ways are *grammatically* correct. Thus, you may use either "우리 한번 가 보자!" or "우리 한번 가보자!"

---

**Usage Note**

한 번 is correct when 두 번, 세 번, 네 번, and other similar counting phrases can be used in place of it; otherwise, 한번 is correct. The following are grammatically correct examples:

- 우리 한 번 더 가 보자! (우리 한 번 더 가보자!)
- 우리 한 번만 가 보자! (우리 한 번만 가보자!)

Comment: I found two tweets by the officials that support that: https://twitter.com/urimal365/status/259199979262971904 and https://twitter.com/urimal365/status/438947487437447168

Answer (score 3):

## Space between the main and the auxiliary

“보다” here is what’s called an “auxiliary verb.” The standard considers spacing before auxiliary verbs/adjectives (“보조 동사”/“보조 형용사”) *correct* and thus you *should*, but it’s not *wrong* not to space it (except for some that you always need to space).

> #### 한글 맞춤법 제5 장 (‘띄어쓰기’) 제3 절 (‘보조 용언’) 제47 항
>
> #### Hangul orthography, Chapter 5 (“Spacing”), §3 (“Auxiliary verbs and adjectives”), Clause 47:
>
> 보조 용언은 띄어 씀을 원칙으로 하되, 경우에 따라 붙여 씀도 허용한다.
>
> It *should* always be spaced before auxiliary verbs and adjectives; however, without a space may it also be *accepted* in some cases.
>
> (And the following is a bunch of examples and exceptions, so you best just space it.)

### ……unless it’s in the dictionary as a single word

But here’s the tricky part. Some constructions do look like a main verb followed by an auxiliary, and turn out are single compound words. Like “살펴보다.” Then you *never* space it. You don’t split a word up into two.

Hold on, how do you know whether it’s a single word or not? Yea, that’s the problem. No good ways but to look up the dictionary every time you get a doubt. Being native doesn’t help at this at all.

Oh, and by “the dictionary,” I mean “[*Standard Korean Language Dictionary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Korean_Language_Dictionary).” Ditch the other. To be *standard*.

### ……which means exactly what you wanted to mean.

If you have found such a word in the dict, the next step to do is double-check if it has the right meaning.

Say you want to say “to try doing (something),” or “to give (something) a try” in Korean. It’s “해 보다.” And you see the word “해보다” in the dictionary. Alright, now then, should you not space it? Yes, you should.

Though “해보다” is a word, it has a fairly different meaning, of “to fight against,” than “해 보다.” Good thing not many words like this are out there.

---

## Nobody actually cares

In my experience, nobody bothers to space the right way. Only pedantic grammar pervs like me do. So to language learners: take it easy.