# Why did the father climb into his own bag? (띄어쓰기 농담)

Tags: spacing, joke

I found this:

> 아빠 가방에 들어 가신다.

But why did he climb into his own bag?

Comment: I think may be we should put things like these in meta

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/when-should-spaces-be-used-after-the-determiners-%EC%A0%80-%EA%B7%B8-and-%EC%9D%B4

Answer (score 2):

It is a well-known meme using wrong spacing.
It should be '아빠가 방에 들어가신다' which means 'Father is entering the room',
but due to the wrong spacing, '아빠 가방에 들어가신다' means 'Father is entering into the bag.'
It's a joke.

Answer (score 0):

The spacing is wrong (띄어쓰기가 안 맞아요).

> 아빠가 방에 들어 가신다.