# One word sentence without space

Tags: translation, word-usage, spacing

While watching some drama, I encounter this sentence:

> **Korean**: 결과나왔습니다화장품뚜껑에찍힌지문은뭉개졌는데
>
> **Subtitle**: The result is out. The fingerprints on the outside of the cosmetic container were smeared and could not be checked.

I'm not sure whether it's a typo where there's no space or it's just that it's grammatical in this case to not use space in this pretty long one word sentence.

When I check against Google translate, it seem to understand and return a translation:

> **Google Translate**: The results came out. The prints on the cosmetic lid were crushed.

**Should there be space in this one word sentence?**

**Or is it grammatical without the space too?**

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/103/when-should-spaces-be-used-between-words?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a "one word sentence". The sentence has 7 words. With proper punctuation it would be this:

> 결과 나왔습니다. 화장품 뚜껑에 찍힌 지문은 뭉개졌는데...

But like many English speakers on the internet, informally Korean speakers don't use punctuation as rigourously as one would in formal writing. This varies by person to person, some people don't use spaces at all when it's unneccesary, some people try to use proper spaces and punctuation as humanly possible. Most people use spaces in a degree somewhere between.

Either way, most sentences are completely understandable without any (or very little) spaces.

Comment: Also, it's not even "a sentence", but rather a sentence plus a part of the next sentence, as you can clearly see.

Comment: Technically, [we could definitely say that it has seven `마디`'s or `소절 (小節)`'s.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437136/what-do-you-call-a-group-of-adjacent-letters-having-punctuation-except-for-apost) However, [it's arguable that it consists of seven _**words (단어, 낱말.)**_.](http://anystory.tistory.com/238)